# Add custom class label to datatable row

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

Is there a possibility to add a costum class label to a data.table row?

I formated my DT row using formatStyle to a yellow background in case a certain condition is fullfilled.

```
DT::formatStyle(1, target = "row", backgroundColor = DT::styleEqual(trans_age(), c("yellow"))) %>%
```

However, the color is not shown when I want to print the table using the print function from my web-browser.
Therefore, my idea is to add a class label to the specific, and to set the colour for the print via  a costum css using @media print.

Kind regards, Silke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `createdRow` option:

```
library(DT)

dat <- iris[1:3,]

js <- JS(
  "function( row, data, dataIndex ) {",
  "  if(dataIndex === 2) {",
  "    $(row).addClass('myclass');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  options = list(
    createdRow = js
  )
)
```

This add the class `myclass` to the *third* row, since indexing starts at 0 in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, the class is not added to the row. Maybe because there is or will be added another class to the row. The class="odd" is set in order to alternate the colour of the rows. Is there a kind of append, or to make sure, that the class is set after the table is created?

Comment: @Rlearner It works for me. Did you check with the inspector tool?

Comment: Yes, it worked as you wrote it. Thank you very much. I tried to compare the index or the data[1] to the value of an R variable, which did not work for me. Can you give me a hint on that? Also, I could not change the style based on 'myclass', but this is probably another problem.

Comment: @Rlearner I don't understand your first question. For the style which doesn't change, maybe you have to assign the class to the cells, not to the row. Perhaps by doing `$(row, 'td').addClass('myclass')` (not sure).

Comment: I tried something like: "  if(data[1] ==", trans_age(),"){", while trans_age() is a variable. Alternatively, I also tried "  if(dataIndex ==", idx_trans_age,"){",. Should something like this be possible?

Comment: @Rlearner You want something dynamic? Or is `idx_trans_age` fixed once and for all?

Comment: Yes, I wanted something dynamic. Trans_age() is a reactive (dynamic) object in shiny. By the way, I could add 'myclass' to td using `$('td', row).addClass('myclass')`. However, probably because of the css of shiny?, my css own does not work.

Comment: Hmm for the reactive class one would have to proceed differently. I don't see why your class does not work. Maybe open new questions. @Rlearner

Comment: A weird combination worked for the case with dataIndex === 2. I added the 'myclass' to the tr. In the css I set .myclass td {background-color: yellow !important'}. Then, my yellow line was shown in the print. The next step would be to used a dynamic value instead of 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. The dynamic worked as well:   `"  if(data[0] ===",as.character(trans_age()),"){",`. I added the trans_age() as character and compared it to my age variable which is given in data[0], in the first column.

Comment: @Rlearner Good :) Could you accept my answer please?